# Get certain value from nested JSON data

Tags: python, json

I use the following code to get a log entry such as:

> 2020-01-11 17:47:16 [root] INFO: A contact with email
>   hunter@tomorrowworld.com already exists.

I wonder if `.get("errors", {})[0].get('message')` is the right way to solve that?

```
if r.status_code != 200:
    if r.json().get("error") == "CONTACT_EXISTS":
        logging.info(r.json().get("errors", {})[0].get('message'))
```

**Full JSON response:**

```
{
    "category": "OBJECT_ALREADY_EXISTS",
    "correlationId": "4a3bf3a8-72c4-47ed-ac27-520ca0bac128",
    "error": "CONTACT_EXISTS",
    "errors": [
        {
            "in": "email",
            "message": "A contact with email hunter@website.org already exists."
        }
    ],
    "identityProfile": {
        "identity": [
            {
                "isPrimary": true,
                "timestamp": 1578760232183,
                "type": "EMAIL",
                "value": "hunter@website.org"
            },
            {
                "timestamp": 1578760232205,
                "type": "LEAD_GUID",
                "value": "79b14936-1215-454a-939d-42071b036bfb"
            }
        ],
        "isContact": true,
        "linkedVid": [],
        "savedAtTimestamp": 1578760232210,
        "vid": 125401
    },
    "message": "Contact already exists",
    "requestId": "2243a2d1ddd19d466ea4b98ab5cf6d66",
    "status": "error"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `[{}]` as a default `errors` value to avoid `IndexError`.

Also you can extract `json()` result not to parse response content two times:

```
if r.status_code != 200:
    content = r.json()
    if content.get("error") == "CONTACT_EXISTS":
        logging.info(content.get("errors", [{}])[0].get("message"))
```

Comment: The only "problem" I see and wonder about is that if `errors` for some reason doesn't exist, the fallback is `{}`. However then [0] would lead to an error?

Comment: i think its not safe to do this json = r.json() , its safer to call it something else

Comment: This is not the right way, because "errors" is a list, not a dict. Also, if the list is empty, it will raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: You are right, I've updated my answer. I've renamed variable to `content`.

Comment: If you aren't importing the `json` module, there's no danger to using `json` as the variable name (though you might want to use a different name anyway lest someone think that the `json` module *was* imported).

Comment: [Plus one] but from perspective of descriptive variable naming `content` is better IMO.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense to use the get method in this `r.json().get("errors", {})[0].get('message')`. Especially with `{}` default. If there's no `errors` element and you try to index a 0th element out of it you'll get an error either way.

If you can be sure each element is present, use normal indexing
`r.json()["errors"][0]['message']`
If you can't - go with `.get()` at each step.

Answer (score 0):

```
if r.status_code != 200:
    if r.json().get("error") == "CONTACT_EXISTS":
        default=[{'message':'key does not exit'}]
        logging.info(r.json().get("errors", default)[0].get('message'))
```